# How can i get yellow lines like the flag in sweden HTML

Tags: css, html

I am new to html and css so i am not that good. The problem i have right now is that i have created a nested table with two tables. I got four columns with the blue color. But the problem is that i dont know how to get yellow lines like the flag has. The code i come so far is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.blue {background-color: #0000ff;}
table.yellow {background-color: #ffff00;}
</style>
<title>HTML Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="yellow" border="10" width="320px">
<tr>
<td>
   <table class="blue" border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
   <td height="40">blue</td>
   <td>blue</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td height="40">blue</td>
   <td>blue</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

(Image of Swedish Flag)

[image]

Comment: For those who don't know offhand what the flag of Sweden looks like: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg/1600px-Flag_of_Sweden.svg.png

Comment: Try 3 rows of 3 columns and apply your yellow class to the middle column and middle row. Then apply widths and heights. Be sure to style your table using `{ border-collapse:collapse }`

Comment: with divs it is much easier: http://jsfiddle.net/a8aaqk9a/

Comment: Thank you guys for you answers! it really helped me to understand now!

Comment: @IamnoobatSQL You can also find a nice "scalable vector graphic" and pop that in there.  What's nice about an "svg" element is that it scales evenly when resizing.  You can feed it inline element tags by percentage for "height" and "width" and the flag will always maintain it's clear visibility as opposed to needing to reset the CSS for each size of page for every page.

Comment: Ty, i will look into that :)

Answer (score 4):

Not table but just div https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/134/

**CSS**

```
.flag {
    background-color: #006AA7;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.flag::before {
    background-color: #FECC00;
    content: "";
    height: 15%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
.flag::after {
    background-color: #FECC00;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 30%;
    margin-left: -5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 9%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Comment: Why jsfiddle rather than stack snippets?

Comment: @Martin Smith I am sorry, but i get used to jsfiddle.

Comment: Yea, I actually like the pseudo element solution here. Well done.

Answer (score 3):

It seems overly complicated to use tables for this. You can very simply achieve the desired result with absolute positioning. Notice how much less code this is:

```css
.flag {
    background: #0000ff;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.vertical {
    background: #ffff00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 300px;
}

.horizontal {
    background: #ffff00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag">
    <div class="vertical"></div>
    <div class="horizontal"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks..just one table.

```css
table {
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
}
tr:nth-child(4) td,
td:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS borders and `border-collapse:collapse`. Adjust the border width as necessary.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.blue {background-color: #0000ff;border-collapse:collapse}
table.yellow {background-color: #ffff00;border-collapse:collapse}
.top-left {border-bottom: 12px solid #ffff00;border-right: 12px solid #ffff00;}
.top-right {border-bottom: 12px solid #ffff00;border-left: 12px solid #ffff00;}
.bottom-left {border-top: 12px solid #ffff00;border-right: 12px solid #ffff00;}
.bottom-right {border-top: 12px solid #ffff00;border-left: 12px solid #ffff00;}
</style>
<title>HTML Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="yellow" border="10" width="320px">
<tr>
<td>
   <table class="blue" border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
   <td height="40" class="top-left">blue</td>
   <td class="top-right">blue</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td height="40" class="bottom-left">blue</td>
   <td class="bottom-right">blue</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lol, you just beat me by a few seoncds, nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the border for every side seperatly per cell:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.blue {background-color: blue;border-collapse: collapse;}
.sweden_cell1 { border-right: 5px solid #ffff00;border-bottom: 5px solid #ffff00;}
.sweden_cell2 { border-left: 5px solid #ffff00;border-bottom: 5px solid #ffff00;}
.sweden_cell3 { border-right: 5px solid #ffff00;border-top: 5px solid #ffff00;}
.sweden_cell4 { border-left: 5px solid #ffff00;border-top: 5px solid #ffff00;}
</style>
<title>HTML Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="yellow" border="10" width="320px">
<tr>
<td>
   <table class="blue" border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
   <td class="sweden_cell1" height="40">blue</td>
   <td class="sweden_cell2">blue</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="sweden_cell3" height="40">blue</td>
   <td class="sweden_cell4">blue</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Also as you can see you need the `border-collapse: collapse;` property to make the borders have no space between them

Futhermore if you wish to make the yellow part wider, just increase the pixel with of the border in the css (which is as 5px atm)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't make that space between columns and rows. You could make table with 3 rows and columns, paint cells in yellow and blue. But here you can find more interesting idea of swedish flag with just one div. http://talgautb.github.io/vexillum/demo/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use border-collapse and add the borders to the cells of the table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.blue { 
    background-color: #0000ff; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:320px;
}
.border-right { border-right: 30px solid #ffff00;}
.border-bottom { border-bottom: 30px solid #ffff00;}
</style>
<title>HTML Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   <table class="blue" border="1">
   <tr class="border-bottom">
   <td height="60" width="30%" class="border-right"></td>
   <td width="70%"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td height="60" width="30%" class="border-right"></td>
   <td width="70%"></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following adjustments to your CSS it kind-of looks like the swedish flag.

I used various different CSS selectors to make this happen, altho I doubt that it'll be easy to understand I'll try to explain

I removed a table from your HTML, it was redundant as the swedish flag yellow areas can be created through the borders just one table.

What I did was gave every `td` element in your table a `border: 10px solid #ffff00` which creates borders around every `td` element.

then after that I used some more complex selectors to target specific `td` elements and remove borders where they weren't required.

So the first `tr` element in the table can be selected with `:first-child` (just like any other first child to a parent can be selected like this). but then we also want the first `td` from that which makes for the total selector:

```
table.blue tr:first-child td:first-child { ... }
```

as you can see below the CSS resets the `border-top` and `border-left` properties as this is the top-left `td` so the top and left part don't need the yellow border.

I simply followed the same principle with the rest of the selectors, targetting specific `td` elements and resetting the borders they did not need.

After that I also added some properties to reset the spacing between the borders to 0 with `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` - these two properties aren't consistently available in CSS so they have to be put in the HTML.

I also removed the redundant `border` property on the `table` because we can set the border through CSS which allows us to be more flexible as we don't have to do styling through editing HTML.

for further reading on `first-child` and `last-child` CSS selectors:

- [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child)
- [:nth-child(n)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

Hope this helps you abit.

Good  luck!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    table.blue {background-color: #0000ff;}
    table.blue td {border: 10px solid #ffff00;}
    table.blue tr:first-child td:first-child { border-top: none; border-left: none; }
    table.blue tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) { border-top: none; border-right: none; }

    table.blue tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child { border-bottom: none; border-left: none; }
    table.blue tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) { border-bottom: none; border-right: none; }
</style>
<title>HTML Table</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table class="blue" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
   <td height="40">blue</td>
   <td>blue</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td height="40">blue</td>
   <td>blue</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it by creating it without tables, and instead layering 2 objects on each other.

What I like about doing it this way like other answers here show as opposed to tables is it shows you a bunch of different powers of css. z-index is a layering style option (-1 for #rectangle places it behind the div). You can play around with the width, height, top, and left values for each to see how they change the placement of the shapes.

```css
#plus-sign {
background:yellow;
width:20px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
margin-left:33px;
}
#plus-sign:before {
background:yellow;
content:"";
width:200px;
height:20px;
position:absolute;
top:40px;
left:-33px;
}
#rectangle { 
width:200px; 
height:100px; 
background-color:blue; 
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
 left:-33px;
}
```

```html
<div id="plus-sign"><span id="rectangle"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice n' easy Lemon squeezie.
Adjust the border widths evenly for a skinnier or fatter yellow line.
You can also change the colors as your see fit using hexadecimal coloring to more closely match the true Swedish flag colors by replacing "yellow" with a hashtag and then whatever color # in hexadecimal for the true colors.  The same can be done with the blue.  Hope it helps! ;)

```css
#swedeFlag{
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#swedeFlag .left{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: solid yellow 10px;
  border-right: solid yellow 10px;
}

#swedeFlag .right{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px; 
  border-bottom: solid yellow 10px;
  border-left: solid yellow 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

#swedeFlag .bLeft{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: solid yellow 10px;
  border-right: solid yellow 10px;
}

#swedeFlag .bRight{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: solid yellow 10px;
  border-left: solid yellow 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table id="swedeFlag" border="2" width="320px" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="left">blue</td>
    <td class="right">blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bLeft">blue</td>
    <td class="bRight">blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp -->
```

Comment: Mike, can i ask you something with html coding, can we take it in private?

Comment: Yes please go ahead MHorstmann15228@gmail.com if you prefer email.